# .net c# APIController attribute testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing

I want to test if my Attributes on the controller functions correctly. The attributes will allow and deny access to resources in the API methods. For a valid request it gets passed straight through the pipe for an invalid request it stops the pipe and throw an exception before the method is reached.

I am using nUnit testing for these test.

So I can test the controller, but I need to test that the attribute does its job for every controller.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use default System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute then you don't actually need to test it, since it [already has been tested by Microsoft guys](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#test/System.Web.Http.Test/AuthorizeAttributeTest.cs).
If you implement custom AuthorizeAttribute then you need to test only your authorization logic (basically testing that actioncontext contains an expected result after invocation of OnAuthorization method with different testing scenarios). Then again yo can look at default AuthorizeAttribute test to learn how to do it for example(using [Moq library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) and [xUnit framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit/)):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using Moq;

 public class CustomAuthorizeAttributeTest
{
        private readonly Mock<HttpActionDescriptor> _actionDescriptorMock = new Mock<HttpActionDescriptor>() { CallBase = true };
        private readonly Collection<AllowAnonymousAttribute> _allowAnonymousAttributeCollection = new Collection<AllowAnonymousAttribute>(new AllowAnonymousAttribute[] { new AllowAnonymousAttribute() });
        private readonly MockableAuthorizeAttribute _attribute;
        private readonly Mock<MockableAuthorizeAttribute> _attributeMock = new Mock<MockableAuthorizeAttribute>() { CallBase = true };
        private readonly Mock<HttpControllerDescriptor> _controllerDescriptorMock = new Mock<HttpControllerDescriptor>() { CallBase = true };
        private readonly HttpControllerContext _controllerContext;
        private readonly HttpActionContext _actionContext;
        private readonly Mock<IPrincipal> _principalMock = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
        private readonly HttpRequestMessage _request = new HttpRequestMessage();

        public AuthorizeAttributeTest()
        {
            _attribute = _attributeMock.Object;
            _controllerContext = new Mock<HttpControllerContext>() { CallBase = true }.Object;
            _controllerDescriptorMock.Setup(cd => cd.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>()).Returns(new Collection<AllowAnonymousAttribute>(Enumerable.Empty<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().ToList()));
            _actionDescriptorMock.Setup(ad => ad.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>()).Returns(new Collection<AllowAnonymousAttribute>(Enumerable.Empty<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().ToList()));
            _controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor = _controllerDescriptorMock.Object;
            _controllerContext.Request = _request;
            _actionContext = ContextUtil.CreateActionContext(_controllerContext, _actionDescriptorMock.Object);
            _controllerContext.RequestContext.Principal = _principalMock.Object;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void OnAuthorization_IfUserIsNotInUsersCollection()
        {
            _attribute.Users = "John";
            _principalMock.Setup(p => p.Identity.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true).Verifiable();
            _principalMock.Setup(p => p.Identity.Name).Returns("Mary").Verifiable();

            _attribute.OnAuthorization(_actionContext);

            AssertUnauthorizedRequestSet(_actionContext);
            _principalMock.Verify();
        }

        private static void AssertUnauthorizedRequestSet(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            Assert.NotNull(actionContext.Response);
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, actionContext.Response.StatusCode);
            Assert.Same(actionContext.ControllerContext.Request, actionContext.Response.RequestMessage);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option for you it to setup integration test using OWIN standalone server
http://www.strathweb.com/2013/12/owin-memory-integration-testing/

Then you can mock your database/data dependency in code and test just attibute handling

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this may help you. Please try POSTMAN tool. 
refer [postman](http://ianswerable.com/asp-net-web-api-google-chromes-postman-plugin/)